# Evaluate $\lfloor \frac{x}{m} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{x+1}{m} \rfloor + \dots + \lfloor \frac{x+m-1}{m} \rfloor $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$  and $m \in \mathbb{N} $ evaluate $\lfloor \frac{x}{m}  \rfloor + \lfloor  \frac{x+1}{m} \rfloor  + \dots + \lfloor \frac{x+m-1}{m} \rfloor $.

Well if $x=m$ then we obviously have $\lfloor \frac{x}{m}  \rfloor + \lfloor  \frac{x+1}{m} \rfloor  + \dots + \lfloor \frac{x+m-1}{m} \rfloor = 1 + 1 + \dots + 1=m$.

If $x=-m$ then $\lfloor \frac{x}{m}  \rfloor + \lfloor  \frac{x+1}{m} \rfloor  + \dots + \lfloor \frac{x+m-1}{m} \rfloor=-m $.

If $x=0$ then $\lfloor \frac{x}{m}  \rfloor + \lfloor  \frac{x+1}{m} \rfloor  + \dots + \lfloor \frac{x+m-1}{m} \rfloor=0 $.

There are many such cases I can think of, but something tells me there might be an easier solution.

Comment: this fucntion is periodic $ f(x)=f(x+m) $ so you could try a Fourier series representation for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [Hermite's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity).  The result will always be $\lfloor x \rfloor$.